# Dart - Arrange realtime data according to same ID

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

HI I had received this kind of data from API (photo below). Somehow I had tried many methods but all not worked out. Is there any method that I can use and how to code using Dart for this kind of data that can trace data incoming and list according to ID ? thank you

```
{"id": "1", "name": "item1"},
{"id": "2", "name": "item2"},
{"id": "3", "name": "item3"},
{"id": "4", "name": "item4"},
------------------------------
{"id": "2", "name": "item5"},
{"id": "4", "name": "item6"},
{"id": "1", "name": "item7"},
{"id": "1", "name": "item8"},
{"id": "3", "name": "item9"},
{"id": "3", "name": "item10"},
{"id": "5", "name": "item11"},
{"id": "2", "name": "item12"},
```

What I was expecting is data name will keep update new if id is same.

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "item8"},
{"id": "2", "name": "item12"},
{"id": "3", "name": "item10"},
{"id": "4", "name": "item6"}]
```

Comment: You can use Map.update method (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/update.html)

Comment: Can you show me the example for this problem, I had tried but the data is stream which mean it keep update every millisecond @VincentDR

Comment: You want to display the data on the console? That's not clear, can you elaborate your question?

Comment: yeah something maybe in array of 4 ids that keep update whenever there's data incoming. Or maybe you have something like the method on how to manage the data structure. I'm quite weak in data structure topic